what program to use to start .desktop files?
I made a desktop file:
[Desktop Entry]
Name=TLauncher start
Exec=sudo java -jar TLauncher.jar
Terminal=false
Type=Application

i changed it to:
[Desktop Entry]
Name=TLauncher start
Exec=sh -c "java -jar TLauncher.jar"
Terminal=false
Type=Application

the problem is what i don't know how to start the code, when i pressing twice on this desktop file its just opening in "Text editor" with what should i launch it? Or how i should do this?

Why are you using sudo there? That won't work, first of all, and is almost certainly not what you want anyway. Does it work if you replace your Exec line with Exec=sh -c "java -jar /path/to/TLauncher.jar? Make sure to use the full path to the TLauncher.jar file wherever that is. If that works, let us know and we can post an actual answer.

@terdon i click on file twice and its open in Text editor :(

Please EDIT the question and mention that, and also answer the other points in my comment. Why sudo? And does it work with sh -c "java -jar /path/to/TLauncher.jar?

Unless you use e.g. dex to open (as in, run) it ftom a shell, I think you'd need to place the file somewhere that your DE (assuming you are using one) would look for such files and "render" them as some application "icons" on a menu or some "launch pad" or your desktop, and you'd need to run it by clicking on the "icon" "rendered" (which will result in the "runner" used by your DE running the file).

See my question on askUbuntu : https://askubuntu.com/questions/969231/17-10-18-04-tls-desktop-files-are-no-longer-trusted
